# setting DataGridViewComboBoxCell value in _CellValidating event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've added a value to DataGridViewComboBoxCell in _CellValidating and I want to select it there, but I can't:

```
private void dgSearchTerms_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
  {
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgSearchTerms.Rows)
    {
      comboBoxCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) row.Cells[1];
      if (!comboBoxCell.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue))
      {
        comboBoxCell.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);
      }
    }
    comboBoxCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dgSearchTerms.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
    comboBoxCell.Value = e.FormattedValue;
  }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on comboBoxCell.Value = e.FormattedValue; I see that comboBoxCell.Value is changed to a new one, but visually nothing happened. The value in datagridview cell remains the same. Why is that?

Comment: You need to clarify how the combo box cells get their items and what you are trying to do here. From what I can see, the cell at `e.RowIndex` `col[1]` IS the cell firing the `CellValidating` event, so “why” would you expect that value to change? I am obviously missing something. Can you clarify, what you are trying to do? How are the combo box cells initially filled with items?

Comment: @JohnG As I said, I am populating combobox on _CellValidating event and I want to set it's value there, but it doesn't work

Comment: Well… I am confident that when the `CellValidating` event fires, the cells value has NOT yet been changed. You can set the cells value to whatever you want, however… when execution exits the `CellValidating` event… THEN the value is changed to whatever is in `e.FormatedValue`. And this looks like what you want any way, so I am not following why you would expect it to be different.

Comment: In other words, comment out the last two lines of code and you will get the same result. Can you produce a small [mre] “with data” for the combo boxes and a step-by-step instruction on how to reproduce your issue? As I said, the code works as expected in my small tests.

Comment: @JohnG I agree, so this is definitely not the place to set the value of combobox, and will try to create one and post it here, thanks